Using pick with rowsums in R
I would like to count the instances where the variables a have been answered (not missing). I tried using pick and rowsums but am unable to find the desired result.
library(dplyr)


anymatch <- function(vars){
  rowSums(pick(all_of(is.na(vars))), na.rm = TRUE)
}


data <- tibble(
  a1 = c("Yes", NA, "No", "Dont know"),
  a2 = c("No", NA, "No", NA),
  a3 = c("Good", "Bad", "Good", NA),
  b1 = c(20, 34, 23, 45)
)

avars <- data |> select(starts_with("a")) |> names()
  

data |> 
  mutate(acount  = anymatch(vars))


like this? summarise(data, across(starts_with('a'), ~ sum(!is.na(.x))))

a data.table approach
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[rowSums(is.na(data[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("^a")])) == 0, ]

to create a subset. counting/aggregating is easy from here.
The regex ^a is used to select the needed columns (name starts with a).

df |> 
  mutate(df, across(starts_with('a'), ~!is.na(.x))) |>
  rowwise() |>
  summarise(account = sum(c_across(starts_with('a'))))


# A tibble: 4 x 1
  account
    <int>
1       3
2       1
3       3
4       1


Alternatively,
mutate(df, account=rowSums(across(starts_with('a'), ~!is.na(.x))))


# A tibble: 4 x 5
  a1        a2    a3       b1 account
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Yes       No    Good     20       3
2 NA        NA    Bad      34       1
3 No        No    Good     23       3
4 Dont know NA    NA       45       1

